# live stock ticker

Tags: php, stocks

I want to display live stock prices on my php website. So, is there any script for this?

thanks

Comment: Please show efforts and contributions by at least showing us what you've done so far so that we can help you improve

Comment: google search turns up many options: http://www.google.co.nz/search?hl=&q=stock+ticker+for+website

Comment: muralikalpana you have 33% accpet rate dont you get answers to your questions on site? or you are just ignoring .

Comment: well, if you get no answers it's time to see if there is something wrong with questions. if your other questions like this one, which is exact google search query, but not collaborative site question, no wonder you get no answers

Comment: Oops, your right, I was just looking at the green and not the gold.

Comment: Real-time Stocks with PHP and JavaScript can be done easily with following some guides that are posted on GitHub https://github.com/pubnub/real-time-stocks/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways:

(1) Use echo to display the live stock prizes if you are using php.

(2) Use html tags.

And the best way:

(3) Work it on your own first and question if there are problems rather than asking on how to start from scratch.

Comment: sorry i am asking about how to retrive first. i am searching a lot but not found opensource

Comment: You may retrieve from your database using MYSQL statements. Then display it using any display function you need.

Answer (score 3):

See the source code here:
http://www.exorithm.com/algorithm/view/stock_ticker